# Access Elements Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mozilla

Can we access cross origin elements or values using window.postMessage?

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage
```

I think for this your site must be XSS vulnerable then.

Answer (score 0):

No.  All you can do is post messages, you have no access to elements or values.  It's up to the developer to determine whether the messages received are valid or hack attempts.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DE4HNB9qfbA <br/> how this guy got access to cross origin Elements?